# After Submiting the form i want to handle the errors within the modal without closing the modal window

Tags: php, html, css

Hello Everyone i was wandering if there is a solution to handle the errors that the form get when the users submit the form so what do i mean is for example if the user give hes username 2 characters i have set the message (Your username must cotain more than 3 characters) but my form is in a modal so when the press submit the modal window disapear without showing the error that i handle with php so how can i make the modal when there are errors in the form to stay on and displaing the errors within the modal i hope i was clear !

Comment: You were NOT clear. The grammar is horrendous, you keep going on without breaks, you have no code to test, and so on. If you want to avoid getting the post deleted, I suggest trying a little bit harder next time. Also, there are several options to do this: you can either do ajax-checks, which will return the error message to the modal, or you can pop up the modal on submit if there are errors. These are fairly easy things to find via Google, or just searching here.

Comment: There are two ways to attack this. It's either you stop the modal from closing on submit and run a client side validation first. Or you still prevent the modal from closing on submit and use Ajax to get the response of your server side validation. To prevent bootstrap modals from closing on submit, change the input type from submit to button. This should prevent a close when button is clicked

Comment: set the <form onSubmit=function(){return false}/> and use ajax to call your php script to check. If there are errors, return errors and show them. If there are non, close the modal..

Answer (score -1):

I did the same for my admin site. What I did is stop the modal closing and when the user finished everything correctly, I will use js to refresh my page or something similar. And if there is an error, I use ajax to show the errors.

Hope it works for you.